# Is the sizeof(ptr) pointing to the first array block always =8?

Tags: arrays, pointers, sizeof

I am getting the size of the pointer (ptr) as 4 which is pointing to the first array block in the temp array. But I was told that it is always equal to 8. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int temp[10] = {1,2};
    int *ptr = &temp[0];
    cout << sizeof(ptr) << endl;
}
```

Output : 4
I think it should be 8.

Comment: That depends on the machine and compiler you are on. If you are compiling for a 32bit machine, your pointer will be 4 bytes, if your are compiling for a 64 bit machine your pointer will be 8 bytes

Comment: But I am using a 64 bit machine. Then, why is it like that?